# What does deterministic mean for getNewAddress

Tags: address

While reading the js library API, I saw this line:

https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/#getnewaddress

> GetNewAddress:
>   If the index is provided, the generation of the address is not deterministic.

I also read here https://learn.iota.org/tutorial/generating-addresses-learn-the-basics

> As previously mentioned, when generating an address you need to know the key index of the private key in order to get the same address each time. The libraries give you two options in order to get that key index: one is to supply it as an optional input parameter, the other is to get it deterministically.

However can anyone explain the meaning of **deterministic**? What can be **nondeterministic** if I use index to generate a new address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you that the attribute **deterministic** is a little misleading.

At the end the crucial point is the assignment or not of the `index` value of `option` parameter in `getNewAddress` call.

1. If you don't assign the `index` value of the `option` parameter, `getNewAddress` call will generate all the addresses for a certain seed, starting from `index=0` and incrementing `index` value until it will find a value for `index` whose related generated address has not been already used in the Tangle. This one will be the address returned.
2. Viceversa if you assign a value to the `index`, `getNewAddress` call will only generate the address based on the value of the `seed` plus the assigned `index` value. In this case, the address returned is not checked as in the case above and it is up to you to decide whether to use it or not in the Tangle keeping in mind that you shouldn't reuse an address twice for payment.

In both cases `getNewAddress` **deterministically** generates addresses but it is in the case 1. where this term suggests some sort of **usability** for the address.